# Why is my anonymous closure only executing once?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add a feature to my list app that allows a user to rename their list's title inline when the page header receives the `.on('click')`event.

I located some code that will allow inline editing ([fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/egstudio/aFMWg/1/).)

However when I include this code in my app within a self-executing anonymous closure, I am only able to rename the list **once**. 
Subsequent attempts to rename the list raise a: `NotFoundError: DOM Exception 8: An attempt was made to reference a Node in a context where it does not exist`.

[My fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/sean_t_taylor/b9fab0vp/14/)

The original code from the jsFiddle above, however, lets a user rename clicked text as many times as needed.

Just need a second pair of eyes. Can't see why this code would run only once and then error out for me but work flawlessly in its origin fiddle.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="_css/bootstrap.css"></>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="_css/noted.css"></>    
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-2">
            <div id="listHeader"><form><input type="hidden" name="hiddenField" /></form></div>
            <div style="height: 50px;"></div>
            <form class="form-group">
                <label for="listName">Note</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="listName" placeholder="New List">
                <div style="height: 10px;"></div>
                <button id="newList" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">New List</button>
                <div style="height: 10px;"></div>
                <label for="itemContent">Item</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="itemContent" placeholder="Text input">
                <div style="height: 10px;"></div>
                <button id="addItem" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Add item</button>
            </form>
        <div id="listMaster"></div>

        </div>  
        <div style="height: 75px;"></div>
        <div id="sidebar" class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-1" style="border: 1px black dashed;">sidebar
            <ul id="listList"></ul>
        </div>
        </div><!-- row -->

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="_lib/_js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="_lib/_js/noted.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>

(function () {  
            var listName, listMaster, crrntActvLst, inActvLsts, itemNos, replaceWith = $('<input name="temp" type="text" />'),
    connectWith = $('input[name="hiddenField"]');

        (function () {  $.fn.inlineEdit = function(replaceWith, connectWith) {

            $(this).hover(function() {
                $(this).addClass('hover');
            }, function() {
                $(this).removeClass('hover');
            });

            $(this).click(function() {

                var elem = $(this);

                elem.hide();
                elem.after(replaceWith);
                replaceWith.focus();

                replaceWith.blur(function() {

                    if ($(this).val() != "") {
                        connectWith.val($(this).val()).change();
                        elem.text($(this).val());
                    }

                    $(this).remove();
                    elem.show();
                });
            });
        };
    }());
$('#newList').on('click', function (){

                listName = $('#listName').val(); 
                listMaster = $('#listMaster');
            //  crrntActvLst = $('#listMaster ul.active');
            //  inActvLsts = $('#listName ul.inactive');

                $('#listMaster ul').addClass('inactive')      
                                   .removeClass('active')
                                   .fadeOut();                              
                $('#listHeader').html('<h3 class="inplace-editor">' + listName + '</h3>'); // displays currently active (new) list in header
                $('#listMaster').prepend('<ul' + ' id="' + listName + '"' + ' class="active"' + '></ul>');   // adds new list to #listMaster
                $('#listList').prepend('<li class="list-group-item" ' + 'data-title="' + listName + '"' + '>' + listName +  '</li>'); //adds list title to #sidebar.        

            }); //add new list event handler 

$('#listHeader').on('click', 'h3', function () {
                $(this).inlineEdit(replaceWith, connectWith);
            }); //inline rename code
}());
```

Comment: Tip: include only the *pertinent* code in your question.

Comment: _"only able to rename the list once"_ How is "list" "renamed" ? Can include `js` at Question ?

Comment: I think the easiest thing to do would be to fire up the dev tools (usually F12), and just set a break point in your code.  Then just run through and inspect the variables to see what's going wrong the second time around.  Just on my phone so it's tough to see, but I would inspect replacewith and connectwith in particular.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and explain expected behaviour compares to result you get

Answer (score 0):

Ok, looking closer...

`replacewith` is defined once (at the beginning), but it's later removed (`$(this).remove()`) on the blur event.  I don't see where it's added again, so it would only work once.